# Check if url is valid or not

Tags: javascript, regex

I tried to check if url is valid or invalid. the checks of 7,8 returns wrong outputs.

```
alert('1: ' + learnRegExp('http://www.google-com.123.com')); // true
alert('2: ' + learnRegExp('http://www.google-com.123')); // false
alert('3: ' + learnRegExp('https://www.google-com.com')); // true
alert('4: ' + learnRegExp('http://google-com.com')); // true
alert('5: ' + learnRegExp('http://google.com')); //true
alert('6: ' + learnRegExp('google.com')); //true
alert('7: ' + learnRegExp('ww.google.com')); //false -> it returns true
alert('8: ' + learnRegExp('www.google.co.il')); //true -> it returns false
alert('9: ' + learnRegExp('http://ww.google.co.il')); //false
alert('10: ' + learnRegExp('https://ww.google.co.il')); //false

function learnRegExp(){
    return /((ftp|https?):\/\/)?(www\.)?[a-z0-9\-\.]{3,}\.[a-z]{3}$/
    .test(learnRegExp.arguments[0]);
}
```

please help me to solve it.

any help appreciated!

Comment: Remember that `www` is just a subdomain. I wouldn't bother explicitly including that in the regex.

Comment: A lot of things can be a valid URL e.g. `http://xyz.mysite.org.ru` I guess the real test would be try and load it

Comment: https://gist.github.com/dperini/729294

Comment: `ww.google.com` is a valid domain.

Comment: Your regex validates `.--.wkh` or `6-..oqw` but rejects `google.fr`.

Comment: I would say that this question is distinct from the proposed duplicate, as ECMA and PHP do use two different flavors of Regular Expressions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this one:

```
 function learnRegExp(s) {    
      var regexp = /(ftp|http|https):\/\/(\w+:{0,1}\w*@)?(\S+)(:[0-9]+)?(\/|\/([\w#!:.?+=&%@!\-\/]))?/;
      return regexp.test(s);    
 }
```

Comment: Unfortunately this runs 'true' for learnRegExp("http://fgsdfjgd") as well, which should be 'false'

Comment: It's fine now, just take note that `s` must be in lowercase.

Answer (score 0):

Problem with 7 is `(www\.)?` is allows 0 or 1 `www.` and `[a-z0-9\-\.]` allows `.`  Since it's only `ww.` then `(www\.)?` treats it as 0 and `[a-z0-9\-\.]` captures the `ww.`.

Problem with 8 is `\.[a-z]{3}` only allows for `.com`, `.net`, etc.  It forces the string after the last `.` to be 3 characters long.  Since it's only 2 characters, it doesn't match.

Don't try to recreate the wheel: [What is the best regular expression to check if a string is a valid URL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/161738/what-is-the-best-regular-expression-to-check-if-a-string-is-a-valid-url)

Comment: unfortunately the RegExp on that page is in PHP, not in JavaScript as was asked...